# Use of a capture name inside a character class

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match a string in the format `/.*/.*`, where `/` can be a slash or another character, and get all characters between the delimiters. Moreover, if this special character is backslashed, it does not count as the delimiter.

For example, if the input string is `/sr\/gs/wfd/`, I want to get `sr\/gs`.

My attempt so far is the following (I also capture the rest, to use it later):

```
/^(?<c>.)(?<my_match>(?:[^\k<c>]|(?<=\\)\k<c>)+)\k<c>(?<rest>.*)$/
```

The strange thing with that it works fine in command line (under Windows cmd):

```
echo /sd\/grs/ | perl -ne "print $+{my_match} if /^(?<c>.)(?<my_match>(?:[^\k<c>]|(?<=\\)\k<c>)+)\k<c>(?<rest>.*)$/"
```

prints:

```
sd\/grs
```

However, when I use the exact same regex inside a script, a compilation error is raised:

```
Unrecognized escape \k in character class passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
m/^(?<c>.)(?<my_match>(?:[^\k <-- HERE <c>]|(?<=\\)\k<c>)+)\k<c>(?<rest>.*)$/ at mytestscript.pl line 188.
```

What is different between command line and script for that regex? Any other regex is welcome of course.

Thanks.

Comment: Are command-line perl and script perl using the same perl?

Comment: @JimDavis: I tested in cygwin (5.14) and Linux (5.18), I can confirm the weird change in behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<!\\)\/(.*?)(?<!\\)\/
```

You can simply use this and grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/41

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot the `*?` modifier which is the key here. Easy to modify for dynamic delimiter!

Comment: That's helpful (with the comment included) - but what is the answer to the question: "What is different between command line and script for that regex?"

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the script and the command line is the missing `-w` on the command line.

Comment: Right! I thought it was an error, not a warning, so I completely forgot to enable the warnings.